Accessing External Drive Content Linked in a SharePoint Online Modern Page Web Part Using Graph API
Is it possible to access content from a personal drive that has been linked in a SharePoint Online modern page web part using the Graph API? Specifically, I need to list the links to all files located in external drives on my site.
I have explored the Graph API documentation and tried accessing shared links and drive items, but I am not sure how to specifically target and retrieve the links to files that are hosted on external drives and linked in a SharePoint Online modern page. I was expecting to be able to fetch these links directly using the API, but I haven't found a clear way to do so yet.
